# where does the incoming traffic come from?

Tags: discussion, linking, statistics, traffic

according to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18238/android-enthusiasts), we have 2,700+ visits/day, which is more than the expected 1,500. The description says

> 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 
>   visits per day is worrying. A great 
>   site benefits people outside the 
>   community. *Eventually, 90% of a
>   site's  traffic should come from
>   search  engines.*

Does anyone know/have access to where the incoming traffic are coming from? If yes, where are they coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analytics of the site are available only to a select few.

I can tell you that the vast majority of traffic comes from Google. Not a surprise, I know.

Answer (score 2):

Ever since Nov 8, we've been skyrocketing upwards.  We're seeing really good growth.  I mentioned the same observation about this stackexchange in the mod chatroom.  We've doubled and nearly tripled our page views.

75% of our traffic is via search engines.  After that, most of it is coming from other stackexchange sites.

Comment: 75% search traffic is pretty good for a 3-month old site. The top non-stack-exchange referrer is Twitter, followed closely by Reddit.

Answer (score 1):

The search engine answer seems the most likely. I know that when I've done a quick Google on answers for some of the slightly obscure questions here, the question itself often shows up in the top 5 Google results.

Also, have a look at the questions with the most views, like the [Galaxy S GPS problems](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/does-froyo-fix-samsung-galaxy-s-i9000s-gps-problem) one. These have thousands of views, and lots of replies from users with just one rep point, that smacks of people who've just found the page through a search engine when they're trying to find the solution to a problem they're having, but aren't sticking around and using the rest of the site.